# Micronaut Kotlin: Rest Controllers not working

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I'm creating a simple application with 2 Rest Controllers with Kotlin. However, for every endpoint
the error is
`{"message":"Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"`

My inferences till now, for which I have searched for solutions and they didn't worked.

1.The generated folders are also empty. Might be an issue

2. As I have tried both IDE and command line. So, ruling out any issue from Idea
3. Tried to add a Java Controller in the project, but that also didn't run
4. Tried to use Micronaut annotations along with Spring Web annotations, didn't worked.

Is there anything else that I can change to make it work?
Ideally I would want to make it work with Kotlin and not Java.

Environment:

IDE - IntelliJ Idea 2020.2 Ultimate
Build - tried both Maven and Gradle, command line and IDE 
EnableAnnotations: Done
Delegate Gradle Runner: Done
JDK: 11 ( but set as 8 in build file)

## Update1 - Got few things working

**Got the base code from Micronaut Launcher site**
My Sample code

```kotlin
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/hello")
open class UserController {

    @Get("/echo")
    fun echo():String{
        return "hello"+ System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

- AOP is not working and thus had to use `@Validated` and `open`. The build.gradle has allOpen plugin.
- `@GetMapping` should work as per https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/#springMvc
- I had to use Micronaut's `@Get` to make it working

Please help in fixing these 2 issues.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong without seeing your project but quite likely the annotation processors are not configured properly. I recommend creating a new project at https://micronaut.io/launch/ and comparing that `build.gradle` to yours.

Comment: updated the question with new findings

Comment: Try make it working without spring annotations first, if it pass then try add dependencies in `build.gradle`